# iOS 8: -[UITableViewWrapperView textField]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

Hello: I've been testing my app on iOS 6, 7, and now 8 (beta 5). My `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`s is working fine on 6 and 7. However, on iOS 8, I'm getting a crash when I attempt to access a subview (text field) of a cell.

I am aware of the fact that there's another view in the cell's hierarchy in iOS 7. Strangely, it appears that this isn't the case in iOS 8. Here's the code I'm using:

```
    //Get the cell
    CustomCell *cell = nil;

    //NOTE: GradingTableViewCell > UITableViewCellScrollView (iOS 7+ ONLY) > UITableViewCellContentView > UIButton (sender)
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        cell = (CustomCell *)sender.superview.superview;
    } else {
        cell = (CustomCell *)sender.superview.superview.superview;
    }

    //Get the cell's index path
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    //etc.

    NSLog(@"%@", cell.textField); //<---Crashes here
```

So, as you can see, I'm accounting for the extra view in iOS 7. After adding some breakpoints and taking a closer look at the variables, I see that `cell` exists, but all the subviews it has in the interface file (which are linked up) - including `textField` - are `nil`. At the line specified, I'm receiving the following crash log:

```
-[UITableViewWrapperView textField]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12c651430
```

I looked into this further, and I found this:

***Changing the `else` statement to be identical to the preceding line gets rid of the crash, and the app works fine (using `sender.superview.superview` like in iOS 6).***

This makes *no sense* to me. Did Apple revert the hierarchy of `UITableViewCell`s to that of iOS 6's, or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Making assumption about the view hierarchy is a bad idea because it changes (as you have seen). The better solution is to walk up the `superview` links until you find the class you need. Then the code will work no matter what.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue. Here's a more reliable method:

```
UITextField* textField = (UITextField*)sender;
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[self.tableView convertPoint:textField.center fromView:textField.superview]];
```

This will work regardless of the underlying view hierarchy of UITableViewCell.

Comment: Accepted this answer because it's shorter and more elegant than iterating through superviews. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Different iOs versions have different implementations of `UITableView`or `UITableViewController`, as an easy fix you'll have to iterate through `superviews` until you found the desired view class instead of relying it being the N-th superview.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This worked, but @geraldWilliam's answer was more concise and doesn't require iteration. +1 though.

Comment: @rebello95 Oh, thanks for the upvote, I agree another solution is better in your case, just keep in mind an option to iterate through superviews, comes handy sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue on iOS8 with getting UITableViewCell via superview from a child view. This is what I came up with for both iOS7 and iOS8 support.

```
-(void)thumbTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Image inside a tableview cell is tapped.");

    UIImageView *mediaThumb = (UIImageView*)recognizer.view;
    UITableViewCell* cell;
    // get the index of container cell's row
    // bug with ios7 vs ios8 with superview level!! :(
    /*** For your situation the level of superview will depend on the design structure ***/
    // The rule of thumb is for ios7 it need an extra superview
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0")) { // iOS 7
        cell = (UITableViewCell*)mediaThumb.superview.superview.superview.superview;
    } else { // iOS 8
        cell = (UITableViewCell*)mediaThumb.superview.superview.superview;
    }
}
```

Just to clarify, in cellForRowAtIndexPath I assigned the tap gesture recognizer. The original design is very complex in Storyboard with many subviews, buttons.. etc.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MediaCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    .......    
    UIImageView *mediaImage = ............
    .....................................
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(thumbTapped:)];
    [mediaImage addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This is far more complicated than it should be. Also, as was mentioned in other answers, you shouldn't be manually specifying how many superviews to go up. Do it dynamically.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'll give that solution a try. Thanks